# How to obtain a WKT from a DotSpatial IFeature geometry?

Tags: well-known-text, dotspatial

I am using DotSpatial 1.9 and I have a feature (sourced from a shapefile).

According to the docs, I should be able to call: `ToString()` on IFeature.

> ```
>     //
>     // Summary:
>     //     Returns the Well-known Text representation of this Geometry. For a definition
>     //     of the Well-known Text format, see the OpenGIS Simple Features Specification.
>     //
>     // Returns:
>     //     The Well-known Text representation of this Geometry.
> ```

But what I getting is the name of the type:

```
feature.ToString()
"DotSpatial.Data.Feature"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug caused by an incorrectly implemented IBasicGeometry.ToString method.

But the WKT is obtainable by: `feature.BasicGeometry.ToString();`

Example tests, GeometryToWktTest and GeometryToWktTest_2:
https://github.com/cumminsjp/Agema/tree/master/examples/dot-spatial-test

[image]